# How to chain async calls

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

We are trying to call the web service which in turn call's another web service. The problem we are facing here is  the web service is a async and it can't wait for the another web service call back,But we get the data only after the second web service call back and that data we have to push it to the first service call back. So Is there any mechanism to make the first web service to wait till the second completes .

NOTE: We tried the following link but we are unable to overcome from the issue.

[How to: Chain Asynchronous Calls with a Web Service Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwba7yy7.aspx)

Comment: Post sample code, what have u tried so far

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I just updated the link you posted to the latest version so that you and other readers can see that "**This topic is specific to a legacy technology**"